# SQL Server : charindex returning wrong index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    substring(Content, charindex(N'<img src=''http://tex.', Content), 
                       charindex(N'class=''latex-formula''>', Content)+22) as Img
FROM 
    [Scyk].[dbo].[Posts]
WHERE 
    content LIKE '%<img src=''http://tex.%'
```

Now I would expect it to give me all `<img>` tags that I have in database. But instead, it returns something like this:

```
<img src='http://tex.z-dn.net/?f=x%3Dlog_%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D64' id='TexFormula' onerror="texError(this)" title='x=log_{\sqrt{2}}64' alt='x=log_{\sqrt{2}}64' align='absmiddle' class='latex-formula'> to:</p><p>a)
```

Where the end of the string ends randomly, it can be few characters too many, or it can be plenty characters too many. What is wrong in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the third argument to substring() is the length of the section you want to extract, not the end index. you would have to subtract the first charindex from the second to get the length.

Comment: Oh. I think you are right, will go check it right away, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is the length not the index.